# Replace text in javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text

```
   var  input="gazanie, flower, blossom";
```

I need to replace input using JavaScript or jQuery.

Output should be like:

```
"#gazanie #flower #blossom"
```

Comment: You could just add a # later after splitting also if you need this for jQuery or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"gazanie, flower, blossom".split(',').map((e)=>`#${e.trim()}`).join('');
```

THat's it :

- split : to split string according to delimitor which is `,` & get array
- map : to add prefix for each element which is `#`
- trim : eliminate space if it is the 1st char or/and is the last char.
- join : to return back from Array to String .

---

## DEMO  :

```js
var input="gazanie, flower, blossom";

var output=input.split(',').map((e)=>`#${e.trim()}`).join(' ');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This leaves an extra space. Output for your solution is "#gazanie # flower # blossom"

Comment: Alright. i update answer

Comment: No it's not. Your solution has extra spaces. It gives: "#gazanie # flower # blossom", he wants "#gazanie #flower #blossom".

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI No it is not. You need to use `#${e.trim()}` instead.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI sir thank you for the feedback. But I don't space after # in my output. Please update your code. Thanks again.

Comment: @AhsanAli : I update it  .. is it useful ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Yes sir its ok now! Thank you so muchhh! :) GOD BLESS YOU.